# Stepping into an else statement after entering the if statement due to curlys

Tags: c#, if-statement

This example of the code works properly, e.g. enters first if, drops out after not meeting 2nd if.

```
if (i < _commandList.Count)
{
    if (output.Length > 0)
        Console.WriteLine(output);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Command.");
```

I initially had coded it as this, which doesn't work. It enters the first if, does not meet the 2nd if as expected, but then enters the else statement and does the writeline.

```
if (i < _commandList.Count)
    if (output.Length > 0)
        Console.WriteLine(output);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Command.");
```

Why does the second code block not work the same as the first block? Since only a single line of code is below the first statement, I thought it was permissible to not have the `{}`.

For reference, the stack frame is:

```
_commandList.Count = 1
output.Length = 0
i = 0
```

Comment: Use curly braces - problem solved. :)

Comment: `Indentation` doesn't mean `Command ordering`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is the "dangling `else`" problem: the `else` always belongs to the *closest* if, regardless of the indentation.

Your first snippet uses curly braces to tell the compiler that the `else` belongs to the top `if`, not to the inner one. The second snippet lets the compiler decide; the compiler applies the nearest `if` rule, and attaches the `else` to the inner `if`.

Comment: My tip: Let your IDE generate curly braces and automatically indent your code. This error won't ever happen again.

Answer (score 11):

dasblinkenlight's answer is correct. I would add to it that this is an instance of a more general principle, sometimes called the **maximum munch principle**. That is: when faced with an ambiguity the analyzer tries to make the *longest possible thing it can right now*.

The `if` statement has two possible forms:

`if (` *Boolean-expression* `)` *consequence-statement*

and

`if (` *Boolean-expression* `)` *consequence-statement* `else` *alternative-statement*

So when you have

```
if (c) if (d) E(); else F();
```

the parser looks at it like this:

- I'm going to try to make the biggest statement I can.
- Ah, there's an `if`. I'm going to try to make the biggest `if` I can.
- OK, there's the condition inside parentheses.
- And here comes the consequence statement. **Again, I'm going to try to make the biggest statement I can**.
- There's an `if`. Again, let's try to make the biggest possible `if` statement.
- There's the condition inside parentheses
- There's the consequence statement. Is there an `else`? Yes! We can make this `if` bigger.
- There's the alternative statement of the `else`, and... we're done the inner `if`. Resume parsing the outer `if`.
- Is there an `else`? No. We can't make the outer `if` any bigger.

The moral of the story is: *get in the habit of using braces*.

Answer (score 2):

By specifying the braces, you are telling the compiler that the else goes with the first if instead of the second if.